# Difficulties with List Comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

For an online course I want to create a function called censor that takes two strings as input (text and word) and returns the text with the word chosen replaced by asterisks.
Example:

```
censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack")
```

should return:

```
"this **** is wack ****"
```

Using a for loop I got the function operable but I want to do it with list comprehension and can't seem to get it functional.

```
def censor(text, word):
    words = text.split()
    result = ''
    censored = '*' * len(word)
    [censored if i == word else i for i in words]
    result =' '.join(words)
    return result

print censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack")
```

However, the print function at the bottom simply outputs `'this hack is wack hack'`

What am I missing here?

Comment: For what it's worth `str.replace` can solve this for you too `text.replace(word, '*'*len(word))`

Comment: @CoryKramer, only if you don't mind censoring parts of words that themselves contain censored words, i.e. [the Scunthorpe Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
[censored if i == word else i for i in words]
```

you create a censored list of words, but you don't keep any reference to it.

Perhaps you meant to assign this list back to the `words` variable

```
words = [censored if i == word else i for i in words]
```

since you go on to use that variable to generate your return value.

Answer (score 0):

Just work backwards from your return. You return result. result is ' '.join(words). And what is words? words is words = text.split(). You are basically ignoring the other lines.

```
def censor(text, word):
    return ' '.join(['*' * len(word) if x == word else x for x in text.split()])

print(censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack"))
```

Answer (score 0):

First,
the return statement is out of function body.

Second,
you need to store the result of list comprehension into some variable.

Below code will work:

```
def censor(text, word):
    words = text.split()
    result = ''
    censored = '*' * len(word)
    result=[censored if i == word else i for i in words]
    return ' '.join(result)

print(censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack"))
this **** is wack ****
```